# I am trying to add 2 values in a SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT f.CaseId
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType = 29 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS AdminFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType =  1 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS SubFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType = 15 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS ContFee
  FROM dbo.Fee f
 GROUP BY f.CaseId
```

For the above query I am trying to add the UnitCost where FeeType=29 and FeeType=1 within the same select statement and Store it in TotalCost.

Comment: I think you mean "..FeeType=29 OR FeeType=1" (assuming FeeType can only be one value at a time).  What have you tried to get the desired sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either you add a new line

```
sum (case when f.FeeType IN (1, 29) then f.UnitCost END) as TotalCost
```

or you use your query as a subquery and make an addition

```
select
CaseId,
AdminFee,
SubFee,
ContFee,
AdminFee + SubFee as TotalCost
from (
SELECT f.CaseId
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType = 29 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS AdminFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType =  1 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS SubFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType = 15 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS ContFee
  FROM dbo.Fee f
 GROUP BY f.CaseId) s
```

Comment: I'm more partial to the subquery, it makes the intent much more clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot I used the add a new line and it worked :-)